# Why do my spells cost the base amount with reduction perks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the appropriate "cast novice spells for have half mana cost" perks and additional armor perks, but spells still cost the base amount of mana. Could this be because I'm a werewolf?

Comment: what do you mean by base mana. When you go to your magicka menu, does flames still show up as 14/s?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the cost is when you look at the spell in the magic menu is what it will cost to cast the spell. What you might be thinking is that your perks reduce this number shown in the menu but that isn't the case.

Sparks has a base mana cost of [19 per second](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Destruction_(Skyrim)#Spells), but in the image the users cost to cast sparks would be 8 mana per second. What it's really showing in the menu is the calculated cost taking all perks and effects into consideration.

[image: Sparks]